# ToastNotifier.GetScheduledToastNotifications() throws "Element not found" (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070490)

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I've noticed in my telemetry data that the following code sometimes results in an exception "System.Exception: Element not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070490)"

```
var notifier = ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier();
var notifications = notifier.GetScheduledToastNotifications();
```

The code is run inside a Windows Phone 8.1 (WinPRT) application on a background thread and the exception is thrown quite sparsely.

Any ideas what might be causing this or additional information I can provide?

Comment: You need to put in the bread first ;)

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem.

It took a long time to figure out, but it's a really easy fix :

"The exception is because you need to provide an applicationId in CreateToastNotifier()"

( [Windows 10: Showing a toast Notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32214716/windows-10-showing-a-toast-notification) )

Answer (score 1):

Maybe late to the party, but in my case it was caused by the fact that I was removing some scheduled toasts in another thread at that moment.