# When i try to make a notification with winrt, it makes an error

Tags: python, windows, notifications, windows-runtime

I am trying to make winRT send notifications.
I tried doing this to make a notification:

```
import winrt.windows.ui.notifications as notifications
import winrt.windows.data.xml.dom as dom

#create notifier
nManager = notifications.ToastNotificationManager
notifier = nManager.create_toast_notifier();

#define your notification as string
tString = """
<toast>
    <visual>
        <binding template='ToastGeneric'>
            <text>Sample toast</text>
            <text>Sample content</text>
        </binding>
    </visual>
</toast>
"""

#convert notification to an XmlDocument
xDoc = dom.XmlDocument()
xDoc.load_xml(tString)

#display notification
notifier.show(notifications.ToastNotification(xDoc))
```

Hoever, it returns this error, when i try to run it.

```
    notifier = notifications.ToastNotificationManager.create_toast_notifier()
RuntimeError: Element not found.
```

My system meets the requierments of winrt

```
Windows 10, October 2018 Update or later.
Python for Windows, version 3.7 or later
pip, version 19 or later
```

How do i fix this error? I can not use other modules, because winrt is the olny one (that I know of) where you can create ui elements on the notification such as buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception happens because you need to provide an `applicationID` in `create_toast_notifier()`
Like this for example `create_toast_notifier("MyApplicationId")`.

This also described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32221222/12971025) but in c#.

Comment: It got rid of the error, but when i run the program, no notification shows up.

Comment: Ive been trying to find a solution for that but sadly I havent been able to find anything.

Answer (score 2):

I just solved this same issue with respect to getting rid of the error but the notification not showing.

This [Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/hh802768(v=vs.85)) advises "Important  You must include the AppUserModelID of your app's shortcut on the Start screen each time that you call CreateToastNotifier. If you fail to do this, your toast will not be displayed."

I then followed the instructions I found [here](https://jcutrer.com/windows/find-aumid) to find the AppUserModelID which turned out to be the full path to my Python executable.

For example:

```py
notifier = nManager.create_toast_notifier("C:\\...\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\python.exe")
```

Comment: Does using [sys.executable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.executable) work instead of hard-coding the path?

Answer (score 2):

---

#### This method is working for me on `Python 3.9.1` and `pip 21.0.1`

---

**Open PowerShell** enter following command `get-StartApps` it returns the `Name` and `AppID`

- See the table or image on [imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwGMb.jpg) for reference.

  ```
  Name            AppID                                          
  ----            -----
  Calculator      Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App
  ```
- This can be handy

  - `get-StartApps | Where-Object {$_.Name -like '*Application Name*'}`
  - `get-StartApps | Where-Object {$_.Name -like '*Python*'}`

**Copy/Paste** the `AppID` into `create_toast_notifier("Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App")`

Example:

```
#create notifier
nManager = notifications.ToastNotificationManager
notifier = nManager.create_toast_notifier("Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App");
```