# Cannot override notification app logo for Windows 10/11 VSTO app

Tags: c#, .net, notifications, vsto, outlook-addin

Outlook add-in VSTO project cannot override App logo when sending local notification, ends up without text or logo when using `.AddAppLogoOverride()`

```
private void CallNotification()
        {
            CreateToastNotification("This is test header", "First line of notification", "...second line...");
        }

public void CreateToastNotification(string title, string message, string message2)
        {
            ToastContent content = new ToastContentBuilder()
                .AddText(title)
                .AddText(message)
                .AddText(message2)
                .AddAppLogoOverride(new Uri("/component/logo.png", UriKind.Relative), ToastGenericAppLogoCrop.Circle)
                .AddAttributionText("My notification service")
                .AddButton(new ToastButton()
                    .SetContent("Open Google")
                    .AddArgument("url", "https://google.com"))
                .AddButton(new ToastButton()
                    .SetContent("Dismiss")
                .AddArgument("dismiss", "dismiss"))
                .SetToastDuration(ToastDuration.Long)
                .GetToastContent();

            // Creates the notification
            ToastNotification notification = new ToastNotification(content.GetXml());

            //set expiration poilicies
            notification.ExpirationTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(120);

            //add handlers
            notification.Activated += ToastNotificationCallback_Activated;
            notification.Dismissed += Notification_Dismissed;
            notification.Failed += Notification_Failed;

            //Adds toast notification to list to persist toast
            toastNotificationList.Add(notification);

            //Sends the notification
            //do not forget to add APPID to CreateToastNotifier()
            //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32214716/showing-a-windows-10-toast-notification
            ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier("MyAppID").Show(notification);
        }
```

My logo.png exists and is copied to output dir

[image: logo.png is copied to output directory][image: directory view to logo.png]

And result is generic notification without passed text or icon

[image: notification without text and logo]

When I comment `.AddAppLogoOverride()` shows text, but without logo.

[image: Notification without logo but with text]

[MSFT docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/send-local-toast?tabs=desktop-msix#adding-images)

Any idea what could be wrong? Maybe Uri?

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Following works only for first notification, if app sends notification again there is same result as previously (no icon but with text). Still looking for help with this, thanks.

---

Ok, it was problem with Uri.
This line works:

```
.AddAppLogoOverride(new Uri("file:///"+Path.GetFullPath(@"component\logo.png"), UriKind.Absolute), ToastGenericAppLogoCrop.Circle)
```