# Toast doesnt show from a console app in C#

Tags: c#, toast

I am trying to implement Toast Notification from Console App in C# using the below code.

I also tried the wpf code, and it works just fine.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.UI.Notifications;
using Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications; // Notifications library
using Windows.Data.Xml.Dom;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // In a real app, these would be initialized with actual data
            string title = "Andrew sent you a picture";
            string content = "Check this out, Happy Canyon in Utah!";
            string image = "http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-01-71-81-permanent/2727.happycanyon1_5B00_1_5D00_.jpg";
            string logo = "ms-appdata:///local/Andrew.jpg";
            int conversationId = 384928;

            // Construct the visuals of the toast
            ToastVisual visual = new ToastVisual()
            {
                BindingGeneric = new ToastBindingGeneric()
                {
                    Children =
                    {
                        new AdaptiveText()
                        {
                            Text = title
                        },

                        new AdaptiveText()
                        {
                            Text = content
                        },

                        new AdaptiveImage()
                        {
                            Source = image
                        }
                    },

                    AppLogoOverride = new ToastGenericAppLogo()
                    {
                        Source = logo,
                        HintCrop = ToastGenericAppLogoCrop.Circle
                    }
                }
            };

            // Construct the actions for the toast (inputs and buttons)
            ToastActionsCustom actions = new ToastActionsCustom()
            {
                Inputs =
                {
                    new ToastTextBox("tbReply")
                    {
                        PlaceholderContent = "Type a response"
                    }
                }

            };


            // Now we can construct the final toast content
            ToastContent toastContent = new ToastContent()
            {
                Visual = visual,
                Actions = actions,

                // Arguments when the user taps body of toast

            };
            //Console.WriteLine(toastContent.GetContent());
            //Console.ReadKey();
            XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xDoc.LoadXml(toastContent.GetContent());


            // And create the toast notification
            ToastNotification notification = new ToastNotification(xDoc);


            // And then send the toast
            ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier("Test").Show(notification);
        }
    }
}
```

I dont see any errrors in the code, but for some reason the Toast is not showing up.

The same code works perfectly with WPF app.

Can anyone help me what i am missing here?

Comment: Did you debug and step through the code? Also is there a shortcut to this app on the start menu?

Comment: There is no shortcut for this app in the start menu. I did debug and i dont see anything through it

Comment: Youll need one for it to work... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38062177/is-it-possible-to-send-toast-notification-from-console-application

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ i did that and still it doesnt work.

Answer (score 2):

I also ran into the same issue with a Console Application where I used sample code from the [Notifications Visualizer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/notifications-visualizer/9nblggh5xsl1) app. This code did not have the `applicationId` string and crashed, exacly as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29315714/4920958).

But after adding an `applicationId`, nothing happened. There were no compliation errors and no exceptions were raised. It turns out you now have to use the [ToastNotificationManagerCompat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.uwp.notifications.toastnotificationmanagercompat) class instead of `ToastNotificationManager`.

Replace:

```
// And then send the toast
ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier("Test").Show(notification);
```

With:

```
// And then send the toast
ToastNotificationManagerCompat.CreateToastNotifier().Show(notification);
```